# error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules, nodes, microsoft-metro

I am getting error, wehen I try to run react native projects.

**opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'**

node: v18.16.0
sample react native version: ^0.64.2

I have done to change my node version with using nvm and so many things but nothing solved this problem.

Comment: Probably your openssl version is outdated. For a quick fix, try to set `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` (but don't deploy that to production; instead upgrade to a recent openssl version).